# Как сделать что бы при вводе в текстовое поле определенного числа, появлялся текст?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-form

Нужно что бы при в вводе в `input` числа ***0***, появлялся элемент с классом `warning`

`warning изначально ему задан display: none`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="price" type="text">
<p class="warning">Неверное значение</p>
```

Comment: А что за запись такая `$(".price:text").val(function()...` ? Где вы такое увидели?

Comment: Да я понял уже что бред

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<input class="price" type="text">
<p class="warning" style="display:none;">Неверное значение</p>

<script>
$('.price').on('keyup',function(){
  if($(this).val()==0){
    $('.warning').css("display","block");
  }else{
    $('.warning').css("display","none");
  }
});

</script>
```

**UPD**

Судя по тому что поле называется price предположу что и буквы там будут ошибкой и  лучше писать код так

```
  if($(this).val()>=1){
    $('.warning').css("display","none");
  }else{
    $('.warning').css("display","block");
  }
```

Comment: К сожалению ваш код не работает

Comment: @RavenTheX - извиняюсь, надо заменить $this на $(this). Поправил в коде